# NestJs Architecture Question: Separating vendor http requests from user driven http requests

Tags: architecture, nestjs

TLDR:
I want to make sure vendor requests are not blocking webserver processes that should be used for user facing requests, and would like to know the best way to do this.

Details:
I am building a [NestJs](https://docs.nestjs.com/) ticketing application that aggregates data from several different third party ticketing feeds, and displays some of this data to end users on our website.

These third party feeds are quite large, change often, are very slow to respond, and need to go through some backend processing before the relevant data can be shown to the end user. Because of this, we are not hitting these feeds directly per user request, but are constantly running data sync jobs that are fetching data from the feeds and trying to keep a local database in sync with them. These feeds communicate over http and require a lot of requests (100k+ per hour)

Meanwhile we have a user facing application that receives about 100k requests per day. I would like to architect the application so that I am making sure that the user facing data is easily available for the running web server and can handle traffic spikes, but also want to keep the application logic as a monolith as both user facing data and processing data share logic, and ease of development.

I am thinking of setting up an instance of the app to handle user facing requests, and another instance of the app for running the data processing work via [Nest Queues](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues). My questions are:

- Is this a good approach to the problem, or is there a better way of thinking about this?
- If this is a good approach, what is the best way to separate the two so that one responds to user requests while the other runs the data processing? Would I use env variables to decipher the current running applications responsibilities and then create the appropriate gaurds, etc., or some other way of directing what each app should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a highly opinionated question so might not be a good candidate for StackOverflow. However, I'll leave a few thoughts here.

There's nothing inherently problematic about having a monolithic application that can have certain functionalities enabled/disabled through external configuration. Just include appropriate flags for which things are turned on.

A potential downside is that when you run multiple instances with different configuration settings those instances are "bigger" than they need to be (eg webpack bundle size or docker image size) but its usually not a big deal in the grand scheme of things.

The longer term trade off is that you'll end up with a lot of conditional logic inside the app which might become harder for developers to reason about, change and test effectively.

If this were my application, I'd personally structure things as a monorepo so that you can extract common functionality into Modules that can then be shared between an API app and a Worker/Queue app. NestJS has its own [monorepo support](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#monorepo-mode) built into the CLI if you want to go down this path.

Alternatively you could look at a tool like [NX monorepos](https://nx.dev/) which also supports a modular approach to having multiple apps with shared logic.

You'll have to evaluate the time and effort trade offs between the different approaches outlined here but if you find that going the monolithic route works best for your organization's objectives then don't doubt yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jesse! I didn't know about monorepo mode but this is exactly what I was looking for. I work a lot on elixir projects, and in phoenix this is called an "umbrella" app and I was looking for something similar but wasn't sure how to implement.

Comment: No problem :) Glad I was able to help